# "Peter loves painting so much that he even worked as a part time art teacher at an elementary school."

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Under the conditions that Peter is still alive and he still loves painting:

> (A)Peter loves painting so much that he even worked as a part time art teacher at an elementary school.
> (B)Peter loved painting so much that he even worked as a part time art teacher at an elementary school.

If Peter is still alive and still loves painting, would (A) be more clear and suitable in **formal/academic writing**?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to emphasize that he loves painting now, or that he loved painting at that time. Eg. if you're introducing Peter as a speaker on a conference, you'll probably use A). If you're giving a speech on the life of Peter back when he was an art teacher, you'll probably use B).

Comment: (B) is appropriate in narrating a story or other fictional work, describing characteristics of Peter. (In this case, 'loved' and 'worked' would both refer to the present, not the past.) It would also be appropriate in giving a 'historical retrospective' of Peter's life, as Maciej mentioned. I feel (A) would be the default in most circumstances, given your conditions.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I agree with you on (B) and update my comment accordingly.